# Generate a formula for x in my case

Tags: calculus, probability, diophantine-equations, problem-solving

Kindly see the following,

```
Gross Total              :      10000
Discount                 :          0
Tax % : 10    Tax Amount :       1000
                         ------------
Net Total                :      11000

Formula: 

Tax Amount = (Gross Total - Discount) * Tax % / 100
Net Total  = (Gross Total - Discount + Tax Amount)
```

Now what i try to accomplish here is, Whenever changing the Net total, the discount amount should be calculated accordingly. By the way tax % is read only. Then Based on the new discount the tax amount should be calculated and hence the (Gross total - discount + tax amount) should match the new given net total.

So in order to achieve it, I just framed an equation like below,

```
Gross total - x + [(Gross total - x) * tax % / 100] = Net total

where x is the discount amount to be calculated.
```

Can anybody tell me whether the above equation framed by me is right or wrong.? If right then can you show how to define a formula to find the x.?  else Kindly guide me to achieve my requirement in a clean way. I meant accurate way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is correct. As for finding a formula for $x$ in terms of the other amounts, let $G$ be the gross total, $T$ be the tax rate, $N$ be the net total. Then, with $x$ the discount as you have it, you want $$G-x+(G-x)\cdot\frac{T}{100}=N$$ $$(G-x)\cdot\left(1+\frac{T}{100}\right)=N$$ $$(G-x)\cdot\frac{100+T}{100}=N.$$ Can you solve that last equation for $x$ in terms of the other variables?

Comment: i just evaluated this equation for x that is                         x = G - ((100 * N)/(100+T)) ..and it's working fine..thnks.

Comment: You are very welcome.